# How to put a component inside another component in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm new at Angular and I'm still trying to understand it. I've followed the course on the Microsoft Virtual Academy and it was great, but I found a little discrepancy between what they said and how my code behave! Specifically, I've tried to "put a component inside another component" like this:

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    directives: [ChildComponent],
    template: `
            <h1>Parent Component</h1>
            <child></child>
        `
    })
    export class ParentComponent{}


@Component({
    selector: 'child',    
    template: `
            <h4>Child Component</h4>
        `
    })
    export class ChildComponent{}
```

This is the same example that they make on the course, but in my code doesn't work! In particular VisualStudio says to me that the 'directives' property doesn't exist in the component decorator. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You *don't put* a component in `directives`

You *register* it in `@NgModule` declarations:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App , MyChildComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

and then You just put it in the Parent's Template HTML as : `<my-child></my-child>`

That's it.

Comment: The Plnkr doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Comment: @Royi Namir, can i somehow add the Template after a click inside the Parent e.g on a button? Without any routes?

Comment: @TheWandererr I don't understand your question.

Comment: lets say i have a parent Component called parent with the selector <app-parent></app-parent>. The templateUrl just consist of <button></button> and the child Component selector: <app-child></app-child>. But i want the app-child to be loaded only after i click on the button.

Comment: @TheWandererr You have 2 options : you can use `*ngIf` on the `app-child` or you can inject a new componenet vs ViewContainerref and then createComponenet

Comment: dont forget to add NgModule into your `import` from '@angular/core'

Answer (score 7):

If you remove directives attribute it should work.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `
            <h1>Parent Component</h1>
            <child></child>
        `
    })
    export class ParentComponent{}


@Component({
    selector: 'child',    
    template: `
            <h4>Child Component</h4>
        `
    })
    export class ChildComponent{}
```

---

Directives are like components but they are used in attributes. They also have a declarator `@Directive`. You can read more about directives [Structural Directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html) and [Attribute Directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html).

> There are two other kinds of Angular directives, described extensively
>   elsewhere: (1) components and (2) attribute directives.
>
> A component manages a region of HTML in the manner of a native HTML
>   element. Technically it's a directive with a template.

---

Also if you are open the glossary you can find that components are also directives.

> ### [Directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/glossary.html#!#directive) fall into one of the following categories:
>
> - [Components](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/glossary.html#component) combine application logic with an HTML template to render application views. Components are usually represented as HTML
>     elements. They are the building blocks of an Angular application.
> - [Attribute directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/glossary.html#attribute-directive) can listen to and modify the behavior of other HTML elements, attributes, properties, and components. They are
>     usually represented as HTML attributes, hence the name.
> - [Structural directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/glossary.html#structural-directive) are responsible for shaping or reshaping HTML layout, typically by adding, removing, or manipulating elements
>     and their children.

---

The difference that components have a template. See [Angular Architecture](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html#!#directives) overview.

> A directive is a class with a `@Directive` decorator. A component is a
>   directive-with-a-template; a `@Component` decorator is actually a
>   `@Directive` decorator extended with template-oriented features.

---

The `@Component` metadata doesn't have `directives` attribute. See [Component decorator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html).

Comment: _"Directives are like components but they are used in attributes"_ Components are directives and can have attribute selectors as well.

Comment: You can use directives in attributes, this is called attributes directives.

Answer (score 3):

I think in your Angular-2 version directives are not supported in Component decorator, hence you have to **register directive** same as other component in **@NgModule** and then import in component as below and also remove `directives: [ChildComponent]` from decorator.

```
import {myDirective} from './myDirective';
```