# Directive that works as ng-if (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I'm trying to create a directive that works as a ngIf to control if the user with the correct permission is allow to see specific content, something like this:

```
<div [type-of-user]="load data from the user and check it (normal or premium)">
    <h3>You are allow to see this.</h3>
</div>
```

I was reading about how to do it and found on this [doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) about "Attribute Directives" but I still can't implement it (I am new with Angular 2)

So far I have this:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[type-of-user]'
})

export class TypeOfUserDirective{

  constructor(private el: ElementRef){}

  @Input('type-of-user') userControl: string;

  private haspermission(permission: string) {
    /*the style background color is just to test if works*/
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = permission;
  }

}
```

I already added the directive in the app.module.

Any advice how to proceed would be great.

Comment: if you are looking for `if` condition you are trying to re invent the wheel .. check [*ngIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngIf)

Comment: directives are used to modify user content, so try to inject some content to directive and modify it.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, at the end I could make it just editing a plunkr I found about directives and an awesome article. @RomanC

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43492590/573032) some round-trips about directives

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After some more research I found a great doc about how to build custom directives, specifically the way I need, that acts as an ngIf directive. You can read about it [here](https://www.codementor.io/christiannwamba/build-custom-directives-in-angular-2-jlqrk7dpw) and see the plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/k2uKCXalbh9tdhLl4bar?p=preview)

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[isAllow]'
})

export class isAllowDirective {

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {}

  @Input() set isAllow(allow: boolean){
    if (allow) {
      // If condition is true add template to DOM
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
     // Else remove template from DOM
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: You may find this article useful as well [Exploring Angular DOM manipulation techniques using ViewContainerRef](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02)

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer doesn't use angular's `*ngIf` implementation.

I've written a custom `*ngIf` directive that uses it:
http://avenshteinohad.blogspot.com/2018/06/custom-ngif-directive.html