# Angular 4 custom directive to hide element is not working

Tags: angular

I am creating a custom directive to hide elements on certain conditions but its not working as per the instruction i found googling.

All other things working but element is not effecting display property

**Use of directive:**

```html
<div manAuthorized [permission]="'permission-string'" class="col-2 data-object-link">
```

**Actual directive:**

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[manAuthorized]'
})
export class AuthorizedDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() permission: string;
  private userObservable: Observable<UserAuthorizations>;
  private currentUser: any;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private configService: ConfigService, private currentUserService: CurrentUserService) {
    this.userObservable = this.currentUserService.getCurrentUser();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userObservable.subscribe((user) => {
      this.currentUser = user;
      if (!this.authorized()) {
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  }

  private authorized() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: in my opinion better approach would be to use viewcontainerref.clear()
a great example here
https://netbasal.com/the-power-of-structural-directives-in-angular-bfe4d8c44fb1

Comment: Another post showing an alternative approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517660/directive-that-works-as-ng-if-angular-2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to handle the style property which have display. as you are trying to set display directly, it did not work.

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Lot of example available online are directly calling display. let me try this.

Comment: may be these were in old version for of angular.

Comment: I was trying to use a `viewContainerRef.clear()` call, but it would not work. Your solution does work.

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(private ref: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {}
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  if (isTeamsWindow()) this.ref.nativeElement?.remove();
}
```

should do it but weird that viewContainerRef does not work.