# How to access a reusable component from one another reusable component and a container component

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, angular8, ng-modules

In our Angular 8 project, we have a container component for user registration (user.registartion). Also, we have a reusable component for updating the user information (user.component). Both components has to show a 'user policy' pop-up which is also a reusable component (policy.component). The following picture shows my project structure.

[image]

But I can't show the Policy popup in both components. It showing the following error on the user registration page.

[image]

How can I access the 'Policy' Component from both the User registration and the User Information component?

Comment: is shared module is imported in user registration module?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put a component inside another component in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492519/how-to-put-a-component-inside-another-component-in-angular2)

Comment: Difficult to answer your question without code. Or else you don't know at all how to import the component so the answer bellow or the official angular doc might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a Shared Module to share components across many **modules** (and everything you want shared, like pipes, directives etc). There is an example in the **[docs](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules)** how to use one:

```
// ...

@NgModule({
 imports:      [ CommonModule ],
 declarations: [ ... your components etc... ],
 exports:      [ ... your components etc... ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Remember to import `CommonModule` to the imports array in your shared module, and export your components. Then `import` the shared module to your other modules.

Comment: By creating a single shared module it eventually grow too large and even if another module is using only one component from the shared module we are still importing the whole shared module I'm facing this problem, can we break the shared modules into furthur smaller modules like separate modules for autocomplete/searchbox, separate module for input/textarea separate module for checkbox/radio button etc because we have our own custom components for these? Is is a good practice or bad? To have these much smaller modules?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import SharedModule on UserRegistrationModule... something like this:

```
@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModukle, // <--- 
  ],
  // ...
})
export class UserRegistrationModule {}
```